# How to dump individual view statements in MySQL

Tags: view, mysql

I want to be able to dump individual view statements/definitions from a MySQL database (version 5.5.28) so I can edit them and insert them into a new database. I've been trying to do it with MySQL Workbench (version 5.2.44 on OSX) but it dumps the views as 'CREATE Table' statements without the view logic.

I'm looking for something to analyze a db, give an options for views to dump, and dumps 'CREATE VIEW...' statements to a file to re-create those views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a [`SHOW CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-view.html) statement that should do what you need.

Example usage, assuming you view's name is `sampleView`:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW sampleView;
```

As a note, your user will need the [`SHOW VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-view) *and* the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select) privileges to be able to use the `SHOW CREATE VIEW` command.

An alternative, you can also get this information from the [`information_schema.VIEWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/views-table.html) table.

Using the `sampleView` name again, the query would look something like:

```
SELECT
    VIEW_DEFINITION
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'sampleView';
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but I have a ton of views and doing them one by one like your first answer would take much longer than I can give. Also the second part of your answer doesn't drop the view names, which I'd have to update individually.

Comment: @wajiw Doesn't `DROP` the view names? You mean like `DROP VIEW sampleView`? If that's the case, you could just use `SELECT CONCAT("DROP VIEW ", TABLE_NAME, ";\r\n", VIEW_DEFINITION) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`. That should give you *every* view preceded by a `DROP VIEW` definition for each. If you want to limit it by "database", add `TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name'` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @wajiw Even-so, you can access the view's name via the `TABLE_NAME` column. You can have the query return to you whatever you need; a simply modification of the `DROP VIEW` sample in my previous comment is `SELECT CONCAT("CREATE VIEW ", TABLE_NAME, " AS ", VIEW_DEFINITION) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`.